# PHP - Unicode characters not displaying correctly in console

Tags: php, unicode, console

Whenever I use PHP 7.2 to print a string to the console and it contains a unicode character to the console, it doesn't display correctly. For example, a `£` displays as `┬ú`.

It's not the console, as I can `echo £` with no problem.

It's not the PHP version. Upgrading it the latest stable version or downgrading it down as far as version 5.6 does not fix it. I've used online emulators using the same versions and they don't have this problem, although they are outputting to a web page. However, it's irrelevant, because I know that this used to work in 5.6 and now does not.

The problem became apparent when I tried to catch an Exception which contained a £ sign in the string. Nothing would happen. The script would halt and no error would be displayed. It took me over an hour to discover that it had something to do with the £ symbol in the string which stops PHP dead in it's tracks, so the problem HAS to be PHP - I just don't know what.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Comment: What OS is PHP running on?

Comment: This has been a traditional problem in Windows but I think it's been fixed in 7.x versions. Are you on Windows 10? Can you see the error message if you print it to a file?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. I'm on Windows 7 Ultimate. It used to work fine. Something seems to have changed. I'm going to try it out on my other Win7 rig and see what happens. I suspect it will work fine.

Comment: Your console is interpreting text not as UTF-8 but as something else, that is all. That you can do `echo £` *using the console* doesn’t prove anything, as that is handling input and output encoding the same.

Comment: Perhaps there are two issues, but it doesn't explain why PHP silently fails when I throw an exception with a £ in the message. Removing it is caught by the catch block as expected.

Comment: There're surely two issues, that's why I was asking if you could see the exception message when redirected to a file.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean when you say "print to a file". Do you mean something like `php script.php > somefile.txt`?

Comment: `chcp 65001` _before_ invoking `php script.php` should help…